# Dynamo DB Delete All Partition Key Entries Regardless of Sort Key Values

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Dynamo table which uses a composite primary key. The composite key is made up of a partition key and a sort key.

Is there a way to delete all entries matching the partition key regardless of the sort key?

I know I can:

```
1)Query for entries where partion key='known_id' and sort key = "all possible values"
2)Delete each returned entry
```

**Is it possible to delete directly without querying first?**

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: Agree with Khalid. I've looked into this several times before and im fairly certain its not currently supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported. You will first need to query for matching records by the partition key.